# Set XMPP connect server on bitlbee

Tags: irc, jabber, xmpp

I have a Jabber (XMPP) account. I'm trying to set it up with Bitlbee, IRC to IM gateway. Let's say, it is called user@foo.com. However the connect server is located at bar.org. In Pidgin, when you press Accounts ↣ *user@foo.com/ (XMPP)* ↦ Edit Account on the tab "Advanced" there is a field "Connect server:", where one can set custom server. How can i do the same in Bitlbee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to channel #bitlbee on irc.oftc.net, i found the solution.

First you add an account: `account add jabber user@foo.com password`.

Then you setup a server: `acc <tag> set server bar.org`, where  is a tag for the account (in my case either jabber or jabber2).

Comment: You may also need to set other options.  You can view these by sending: "account <tag or #> set" (without the quotes) and then setting the option with "account <tag or #> set option value".  Example: acc 5 set password BlahBlahBlah